# setTimeout use closure context in strange way

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a `debounce` function like `var debounced = debounce(my_func, delay);`

The `debounce` function makes sure that:

1. During delay `my_func` may be executed only once
2. `my_func` will be called not earlier that `delay` ms

So here it is:

```
var debounce = function(fn, delay) {

    var scheduled;

    return function() {     
        var that = this; // save context
        console.log('this = ' + that);

        if (!scheduled) {
            scheduled = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                scheduled = false;  
                //PROBLEM: `that` variable is always the same as on the first function call
                console.log('executing... \nthis = ' + that);                   
                fn.apply(that); //call function in saved context
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    var ctx;
    var debounced = debounce(function() {
      ctx = this;
    }, 10);
    debounced.call(11);
    debounced.call(22); // PROBLEM: it leads to function invoked with this == 11 instead of this == 22
```

prints to console

```
"this = 11"
"this = 22"
"executing... 
this = 11" // INSTEAD OF "this = 22"
```

Comment: And what do you expect if that `if (!scheduled)` branch is preventing second call to be posted into the queue? So your logic is first-come-first-served-others-ignored.

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect it to echo `this = 22` anyway. With the second call, `scheduled` is true, so the timeout isn't set and the function isn't executed.

Comment: @c-smile @Matt Burland right, but I override `that` argument on each call. So I expact at the moment of `fn.apply` that will be 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
var debounce = function(fn, delay) {
    var that = {};
    var scheduled, last_fn;

    return function() {     
        that.a = this;
        console.log('this = ' + that.a);

        if (!scheduled) {
            scheduled = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                scheduled = false;
                console.log('executing... \nthis = ' + that.a);
                fn.apply(that);
            }, delay);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: What you was trying to do was sending a new data as ref, but how you try it, it was by value. The way you can do it in javascript is to change a value on an object.

Comment: but how about classical js-book closure examples? I mean `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) $el.click(function() { console.log(i); })`. Why it update `i` inside inner function? After clicking on the first element it'll log `4` instead `0`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `debounced.call(11)` the first time `that == 11` in the context of the call and as `!scheduled == true` a timeout is set within this context

The next call `debounced.call(22)` stores 22 as that in the context of this call, which is not the same as the one in which the `setTimeout` was called.

The solution is to store the variable outside the context of the returned function from `debounced` as Doron pointed out.